# Is there a way to run compatibility mode in Metro IE10 (not in desktop mode)?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-8

I am trying to get the "Metro" version of IE 10 to run in compatibility mode. The web application I am using was written for IE 9 and earlier and has some issues in IE 10.

I have been able to run the application in compatibility mode in "desktop" IE 10 but the fluidity of the application is not the same (using tablets so touch input is all we have).

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to... Desktop --> IE --> tools --> Compatability View Settings --> Check “Display all websites in Compatability mode”.

This setting, applied in the desktop version of IE, applies to the tile version (or IE Metro) as well.